# Viewflippers and TabHosts in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, viewflipper

What i am trying to do is have a ViewFlipper flip between two TabHosts is this possible?
Could someone point me to simple example before  I start posting messy xml files that probably confuse more than help.

Consider the following image. Say the you have to categories Rock/ and Pop. What i would like to do is be able to have a single Activity that would flip the below tabs according to each Category using a (flip me) button.

[image]

My problem rises when my Activity that extends TabActivity when flipped tries to call getTabHost() and host.getTabWidget() a NullPointerException is thrown... and my application crashes...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong : what i understood is when i swipe in activity of current tab, it should display the activity of next tab ?..Or you want to have view flipper inside current tab. ie. in current tab if activity1 is displayed, and if i swipe, it must show me activity2 in the same tab only.

Comment: Sorry bad description of my problem.  I edited my post to try and  highlight my problem.

Comment: So in your Artists tab, there will be two categories, Rock and Pop (Shown as buttons). And when i click on Rock, it should me pop up me with something. same with Rock ??????

Comment: No Not exactly! i would like to implement the following. By clickicking the (flip me) button flip the entire Tab Layout (Artists,Albums,Songs) and show only Pop artists,albums,songs and then flip back to Rock

Comment: Ok. This is what you really want. See the complete tutorial here : http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory . Try this and tell me the result

Comment: I read the article very interesting, but no, i dont want a viewflipper within a tab. I want one outtside of it. I want the Viewfliper to flip between two sets of identical tabs....

Comment: Ok. You wan to flip entire tabhost ?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I require

Comment: Any ideas would be appreciated cause i am really stuck